# Squeeze things in sculpt mode? - 2.8

Tags: sculpting, eevee-render-engine

I would like to know if there is a way to move a portion of the sculpture "downwards", like smooshing it so it  can be more at the same level of it's surroundings, but preserving its  outlines and main shape, losing the minimal amount of detail.

Like in this simple example of an eyeball, the iris is with too high elevation:

[image]

I could use the grab brush from different angles pushing it downwards, but it seems inefficient...

Maybe the best way of doing this is in edit mode then?

I know this example doesn't have much detail and would be faster making it from scratch, but I would like to know: what is the best workflow in cases like this? Is there a nice technique to squash things?

Thanks!

Comment: look into proportional edit setting, hotkey = o

Comment: Thanks! It does work very well! But then there is no other efficient way of achieving the same results only in sculpt mode right?

Comment: Been a while since I've been in the sculpt toolbox, but there is a shrink brush.  If in doubt save a copy and experiment.

Comment: Do mean the deflate brush? I tested it to deflate the whole area, it loses some of the detail, but not all... Hmmm... I guess it could work in some cases

Comment: So many new brushes in 2.81 I have no idea, you should have a look at the [blender today live](https://www.youtube.com/user/BlenderFoundation/videos?view=0&sort=dd&flow=grid) videos, they covered the new ones in the last episode.

Comment: :0 woa!  
I didn't know! Thanks! There seems to be some pretty neat new stuff! I'm gonna check it. I have to stay more tuned for the blender community, but they could also put an update notification on the software XD